# Python daemon exits silently in urlopen

Tags: python, raspberry-pi, urllib2, daemon, urllib

I have python daemon started from a init.d script. The daemon optionally reads an array of id:s from a server through a REST interface. Otherwise I use an array of pre-defined id:s.

```
logger.info("BehovsBoBoxen control system: bbb_domoticz.py starting up")


if DOMOTICZ_IN or DOMOTICZ_OUT:
#
# build authenticate string to  access Domoticz server
#

  p = urllib2.HTTPPasswordMgrWithDefaultRealm()
  p.add_password(None, DOMOTICZ_URL, USERNAME, PASSWORD)

  handler = urllib2.HTTPBasicAuthHandler(p)
  opener = urllib2.build_opener(handler)
  urllib2.install_opener(opener)




  if DOMOTICZ_IN:
#
# Find all temperature sensors in Domoticz and populate sensors array
#
    url= "http://"+DOMOTICZ_URL+"/json.htm?type=devices&filter=temp&used=true&order=Name"
    logger.debug('Reading from %s',url)
    response=urllib2.urlopen(url)
    data=json.loads(response.read())
    logger.debug('Response is %s',json.dumps(data, indent=4, sort_keys=True))
    for i in range(len(data["result"])):
      a=data["result"][i]["Description"]
      ini=a.find('%room')
      if ini != -1:
         ini=ini+6
         rIndex=int(a[ini:])

      logger.info('Configure room id %s with Domoticz sensor idx: %s', rIndex,  data["result"][i]["idx"])

      sensors[rIndex]=data["result"][i]["idx"]
```

The daemon is started from an init.d script at boot. Everything works perfectly if I use the option with predefined id:s, i.e. I don't use the REST interface. The daemon starts at boot, and I can stop and restart the deamon with the command

sudo service start/stop/restart

However, if I use the other option (read id:s from server), the daemon does not start at boot. In the log file I find one single line ("...bbb_domoticz.py starting up"). Henze, the daemon exits silently right after this, probably in one of the following urllib2 calls. The following logger.debug('Reading...') does not show up in the log-file.

But the strange thing is if I manually start the daemon with a copy of the init.d script in my home directory, the daemon starts. If I run the init.d script from /etc/init.d, the deamon immediatly exits as it does at boot. But if start the daemon with the script in my home directory, I can continue to start/stop/restart with the service command.

So my taking from this is something goes wrong in urllib2 unless I have managed to start the daemon once from my home directory. It puzzles me I don't get any traceback or anything when the daemon exits.

Any idea how to nail down this problem?

Edit: Inspired by the answer to add logging to specific modules, I tried to add logging to urllib2. However, I can´t figure out how to let this module use my logging  handler. Help on this is appreciated.

Comment: For starters you could insert a bunch of `log.debug` statements, call `service restart`, and check the logs.

Comment: Alternatively, `pip install asdb`, insert `import asdb;asdb.set_trace()` at the top of the file, restart the service, and then run `asdb` at the terminal. That should get you into a debugger that you can step through.

Comment: Run it interactively, rather than starting it as a service.  Then you'll (a) potentially see output that is being lost because you're running it as a service and (b) you can just use the normal Python debugger.

Comment: The thing is everything works fine when running it interactively. And it is just the peculiar case when the deamon is started from /etc/init.d at boot the problem appears. I tried to throw in logger.debug statement in urllib2 module, but I can't figure out how to reach the logger handler I created in the main module...